# Adding some JPanels (one below another) in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, jpanel

I'd like to add some panels (with different height) to another `JPanel` (which is in a `JScrollPane`) as in this image:

[image]

Which layout should I use?

Comment: Looks like a good fit for [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html).  See also [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for a quick 'birds eye view'.

Comment: Ahh!!! I forgot about BoxLayout. Thanks for advice:)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Why not put that comment as an answer, its weird to see a question like this;with no answer :)

Comment: @Sanjay  Good point, done.  I make 'judgement calls' on each comment/answer at the moment I am posting, and don't always make the best decision.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a good fit for [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html). See also [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for a quick 'birds eye view' of the layouts available in the J2SE.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest is to use flowlayout and set the preferred height of the JPanels accordingly http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html

If you plan to do more with your layout I'd recommend one of the more advanced third party layouts like JGoodies Form Layout http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/ You'll need to learn more, but than you have a good flexible layout which will solve most of the real world problems you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but FlowLayout is not layout that I search. As Andrew write BoxLayout will resolve the problem.